# How To Display first 50 characters Of Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How To Display 1st 50 characters Of Text by   using , html, css, javascript, jquery . and after 50 charecters create link for show the total text

Comment: i tried this   text-overflow: ellipsis; but its not working

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXhLd/1/)**

try this:
in html

```
<div class='str'>
How To Display 1st 50 characters Of Text by using , html, css, javascript, jquery . and after 50 charecters create link for show the total text
</div>
```

in js

```
var string = $('.str').text();
var str50 = string.substr(0,50) 
$('.str').html(str50+'...'+'<a class="readmore" href="#">readmore</a>');
$('.str').attr('data-text',string);

$('.readmore').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().html($(this).parent().attr('data-text'))

})
```

if you want use more object use `$.each`

Answer (score 2):

Following code may help you..

**HTML**

```
<div id="showText"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  $('#showText').html(text.substring(0,50)+"<a id='showDetails' href='javascript:void(0);'>Show Details</a>");
  $('#showDetails').on('click',function(){
  $('#showText').html(text);
  });
});
```

***Or you can check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R5pU3/) Link***

Answer (score 0):

Shorten plugin was available in jquery

[Reference Link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/)